# LIbreOffice new sheet different template

Tags: libreoffice

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu. I'm running 14.04.
I'm having an issue with LibreOffice. I created a template (Calibri,16) and saved it as a template, then set it as default template. However, if I open a new sheet, it opens with a different template (Liberation Sans,10).
I don't know if this happens to me only.

Answer (score 1):

Chad, Thanks a bunch it worked for me!!!!!

To Create a Default Template

- Create a document and the content and formatting styles that you want.
- Choose File - Save As Template.
- In the New Template box, type a name for the new template.
- In the Categories list, select "My Templates", and then click OK.
- Choose File - New - Templates.
- Double-click the "My Templates" folder.
- Click on the template that you created, and click Set as Default.
- Close the dialog.

Taken from: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Changing_the_Default_Template